# Error 404 while checking IndexExists() in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a function which creates the connection with elastic search and push the documents.

```
public static void CreateIndex<T>(string indexName, string aliasName, List<T> documents) where T : class
        {
            ElasticClient elasticClient = CreateElasticClient(indexName);

            // create new bucket if not exists
            if (!elasticClient.IndexExists(i => i.Index(indexName)).Exists)
            {
                elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, s => s.AddMapping<T>(m => m
                .MapFromAttributes()));
            }

            // create indexes
            var response = elasticClient.IndexMany<T>(documents);
         }
```

It is giving 404, remote server does not exists error for elasticClient.IndexExists() if the index does not exists. But still creating the documents in elastic search along with new index.
Below is the function i am using to establish connection (CreateElasticClient)

```
private static ElasticClient CreateElasticClient(string indexName)
        {
            var connectionString = "http://localhost:9200/"
            Uri uri = new Uri(connectionString);
            ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri, defaultIndex: indexName);
            settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p);
            ElasticClient elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var rootNodeInfo = elasticClient.RootNodeInfo();

            if (!rootNodeInfo.ConnectionStatus.Success)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to Elastic search!", rootNodeInfo.ConnectionStatus.OriginalException);
            }

            return elasticClient;
        }
```

Comment: That reads very nice, but what's the question?